# Auto shutdown when no HDD activity

Tags: server, hard-drive, shutdown

I have a media server with 6 hard drives. I use it 2 - 3 times a week, so it would be a waste of electricity if the server is turned on 24/7. So I want to shut it down when it is not in use, automatically.

The solution would be that when Ubuntu detects no hard drive activity on one of the drives, the server would shut down after about 15 minutes or so. How can I set something like this up?

The server should not check for activity on the startup HDD, but only on the 5 HDD's that contain all the media files.

I new to Ubuntu so I have no idea how this could be done.